# Automatically saving history in R across sessions

Tags: r

I have an environment variable `$R_HISTFILE` pointing to `/home/my.username/.RHistory` and the following code in my `.Rprofile` in my home directory:

```
.Last <- function() {
        if (!any(commandArgs()=='--no-readline') && interactive()){
                require(utils)
                try(savehistory(Sys.getenv("R_HISTFILE")))
        }
}
```

Still whenever I open R, and I do `history()` I can't see the commands that I typed in earlier sessions. Moreover, the files `.RHistory` is pretty much empty with only three lines, (not at all reflecting commands I typed in the past).

How can I automatically save my history of commands across R sessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you set the environment variable?  You should be able to put it in your `.Renviron` file.

To make sure the environment variable is being set correctly, confirm that this gives you "/home/my.username/.RHistory"

```
$ R --slave -e 'Sys.getenv("R_HISTFILE")'
```

Otherwise, are you starting `R` with `--vanilla` or similar?  Are you in your home directory when you start R?

It works for me:

```
gMac:~ garrett$ R_HISTFILE=~/.RHistory R --vanilla -q
> .Last <- function() {
+         if (!any(commandArgs()=='--no-readline') && interactive()){
+                 require(utils)
+                 try(savehistory(Sys.getenv("R_HISTFILE")))
+         }
+ }
> a <- 5
> b <- 10
> q()

gMac:~ garrett$ R_HISTFILE=~/.RHistory R -q
> history()
```

which gives me a file with the following contents:

```
.Last <- function() {
        if (!any(commandArgs()=='--no-readline') && interactive()){
               require(utils)
               try(savehistory(Sys.getenv("R_HISTFILE")))
        }
}
a <- 5
b <- 10
q()
history()
```

---

If all else fails, you could put `loadhistory(Sys.getenv("R_HISTFILE"))` in `.First` in your .Rprofile.